# Get initials from name input by user

Tags: c, strings

This was an exercise from cs50. The goal was to get the initials in upper letter of a name that we got from user. So for "barack obama" we would get "BO", input like "abc" should output "A" and so on. I am interested in knowing what I can do to simplify it or be more efficient.

Do I need the check against `'\0'` in the `while` loop? I ask because the way I see it, when a user inputs a name, there will always be a '\n'(right ?), so it gets out of the `while` loop when its position has `'\n'` and then out of for loop so `'\0'` is never actually checked. Let me know if logic is right. I kept it there just in case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NAME_LEN 80 + 1

int main(void)
{
    char userName[NAME_LEN], userInitials[NAME_LEN];
    int i, pos = -1;

    // ask user for a name
    fgets(userName, NAME_LEN, stdin);
    for(i = 0; userName[i] != '\n' && userName[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (userName[i] >= 'a' && userName[i] <= 'z')
        {
            userInitials[++pos] = userName[i] - ('a' - 'A');
        }
        else
        {
            userInitials[++pos] = userName[i];
        }
        while ((!isblank(userName[i])) && (userName[i] != '\n') && (userName[i] != '\0'))
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    userInitials[++pos] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", userInitials);

}
```

Comment: "_Do i need the check against '\0' in the while loop?_" -- Yes. "_when a user inputs a name there will always be a '\n'(right ?)_" -- Only when there is enough space. If the user types more than 79 characters for the `fgets`, there won't be a `\n`.

Comment: I made so many changes that I though it would be appropriate to post another question: [Capitalised initials of username](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/96576/capitalised-initials-of-username)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The compiler doubles as a code-analysis tool**

Compiling your file like: `gcc usename.c -Wall -pedantic` Warns you of a bad practice in your code:

```
usename.c:12:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     fgets(userName, NAME_LEN, stdin);
```

You should use the return value to check if input reading happened correctly.

**Small helper function to increase readibility**

The line

```
userInitials[++pos] = userName[i] - ('a' - 'A');
```

is not so immediate to understand, I suggest writing a tiny function:

```
char to_uppercase(char letter) {
    return letter - ('a' - 'A');
}
```

and calling it like:

```
 userInitials[++pos] = to_uppercase(userName[i]);
```

**The C99 Standard and variable scope**

All major C compiler support C99, I suggest using the appropriate flag to enable it and write:

```
for(int i = 0; userName[i] != '\n' && userName[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

to shorten the scope of `i`.

**Excellent parametrization**

You defined a constant for `NAME_LEN` and named it meanigfully instead of sprinkling a random number all over your code, excellent!

For further improvement I suggest using a

```
static const int NAME_LEN = 80 + 1
```

For reasons discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c).

Answer (score 3):

Good for you, using `fgets()` instead of the insecure `gets()`.

To answer your question, yes you need to check for the NUL terminator.  You cannot rely on the newline being there, because:

- The input might be longer than 80 characters, in which case the string will have been truncated with a NUL before the newline.
- The input might not come from a user typing into your program.  It could be any data piped to your program's `stdin`.  For example, `echo -n Barack Obama | print_initials` in a Bash shell would feed a string to your `print_initials` program that contains no newline.

You could make more effective use of the standard C library.  In particular, you might be interested in <s>`strpbrk()`</s> `strspn()` to find the next blank character and `toupper()` to convert to uppercase.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> I had originally recommended `strpbrk()`, but after [having solved the function myself](/a/96643/9357), I found that [`strspn()` and `strcspn()` is more useful](//stackoverflow.com/q/24583313/1157100).

Comment: What does `strpbrk` stand for?

Comment: @Caridorc "Pointer to the next break" or something like that. Anyway it turns out that `strspn()` and `strcspn()` are more appropriate.